# R: Interacting text-variables/dummies with each other or other variables

Tags: r, regression, interaction, dummy-variable

The columns in my dataset look something like this:

*Date ¦ Company_id ¦ Headquarters ¦ Industry ¦ Returns ¦ Dummy1 ¦ Fundamental_factor1 ¦ Fund_factor2 ¦ ...*

Note that Headquarters and Industry are not in dummy format, i.e. they are for example "NY" (HQ in New York) and "Services" (exemplary Industry). Dummy1, however, is already in dummy format (1 for what I'm interested in, 0 for other types of firms).

Moreover, the regressions I am running are in the cross-section for around 4,000 companies. So the date column is the same date for all.

**Now to my issue:** My initial regression in R was simply lm(Returns ~ Dummy1) to analyze differences-in-means. Now I would like to control for industries and/or headquarters (HQ). These regressions work fine:
lm(Returns ~ Dummy1 + Industry) or the same with HQ. However, I would also like to add interaction terms with Dummy1 -> this is where I am having issues.

I know that I could create dummies for all the HQ and Industries and manually add each dummy to the regression. But with 40 HQs and 20 Industries, this is quite cumbersome.

Would be really thankful to get some tips on how to proceed. I have also thought about using plm() function with Industry / HQ fixed effects, but I still wouldn't know how to interact them with my Dummy1.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you have those variables set as factors, R will dummycode them for you under the hood. See what happens when you run `lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Unfortunately, this doesn't help me though. I have already managed to get R to make dummies automatically, but I cannot automatically make an Interaction term with it (because it is not a number).